# Reactor Feign cannot deserialize Flux response

Tags: json, spring-webflux, reactor, feign

I have the following controller

```
@RestController
public void MyController {
  @GetMapping("/foo")
  public Flux<Foo> getFoos() { /* return a flux of Foos*/ }
}
```

And a Feign client

```
public interface MyFeignClient {
  @RequestLine("GET /foo")
  Mono<Foo> getFoos();
}

public class MyClients {
  public static MyFeignClient myFeignClient() {
    return ReactorFeign.builder().target(MyFeignClient.class, "http://localhost:8080");
  }
}
```

But when I call

```
StepVerifier.create(myFeignClient.foo())
  .consumeNextWith(foo -> println(foo))
  .verifyCompleted();
```

I got this error

> java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "consumeNextWith" failed
>   (expected: onNext(); actual: onError(feign.FeignException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of
>   `com.example.Foo` out of
>   START_ARRAY token  at [Source: (BufferedReader); line: 1, column: 1]
>   reading GET
>   http://localhost:8080/foo))
>
> at
>   reactor.test.ErrorFormatter.assertionError(ErrorFormatter.java:105)
>     at reactor.test.ErrorFormatter.failPrefix(ErrorFormatter.java:94)   at
>   reactor.test.ErrorFormatter.fail(ErrorFormatter.java:64)  at
>   reactor.test.ErrorFormatter.failOptional(ErrorFormatter.java:79)  at
>   reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.lambda$consumeNextWith$1(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:256)
>     at
>   reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$SignalEvent.test(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:2112)
>     at
>   reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onSignal(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1408)
>     at
>   reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onExpectation(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1356)
>     at
>   reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onError(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1030)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxTake$TakeSubscriber.onError(FluxTake.java:138)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onError(FluxSubscribeOn.java:157)
>     at
>   feign.reactive.ReactiveInvocationHandler$1.request(ReactiveInvocationHandler.java:115)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.requestUpstream(FluxSubscribeOn.java:131)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxSubscribeOn.java:124)
>     at
>   feign.reactive.ReactiveInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeMethod$0(ReactiveInvocationHandler.java:99)
>     at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSource.subscribe(FluxSource.java:52)
>     at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7777)    at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FluxSubscribeOn.java:194)
>     at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)   at
>   reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)    at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)    at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)  Suppressed:
>   feign.FeignException: Cannot deserialize instance of
>   `com.example.Foo` out of
>   START_ARRAY token  at [Source: (BufferedReader); line: 1, column: 1]
>   reading GET
>   http://localhost:8080/foo         at
>   feign.FeignException.errorReading(FeignException.java:130)        at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:162)
>         at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:80)
>         at
>   feign.reactive.ReactiveInvocationHandler$1.request(ReactiveInvocationHandler.java:109)
>         ... 13 more     Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of
>   `com.example.Foo` out of
>   START_ARRAY token  at [Source: (BufferedReader); line: 1, column: 1]
>         at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
>         at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
>         at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1139)
>         at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1093)
>         at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1461)
>         at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:185)
>         at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
>         at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
>         at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3063)
>         at feign.jackson.JacksonDecoder.decode(JacksonDecoder.java:61)      at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.decode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:183)
>         at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:147)
>         ... 15 more

What have I done wrong here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search shows that the feign client does not support reactive. They have an incubating project trying to create support

[Add Webflux support issue](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-reactive/issues/20)

[Feign core](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/361)

**So to answer your questions**

*"What have i done wrong?"*

You have chosen to use an HttpClient that does not support producers/consumers.

*"How can i fix it?"*

By not using the feign client and instead use an HttpClient that supports non blocking operations, like for instance, the spring WebClient.

Comment: thanks @Thomas, I'm using reactive feign extension https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-reactive, but you're probably right about not all the issues have been fixed

Comment: sorry, I'm just thinking that you're right. Didn't have time to verify it yet